# WSRM error on Server running SQL databases

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows

I have a Server Running Windows Server 2008 Enterprise Edition With SQL 2005. There is no problems with the server in its day to day functions but i am getting a Warning in the Event Log every 5 minutes with the following:

> Windows System Resource Manager encountered the following error 0x80010117. User Name will not be logged in the subsequent event logs.
>
> Error 0x80010117
>
> User Action
>   Address the error condition, and then try again.

This has been happening for over 2 weeks now and i cannot find anything online to help!

If i could have some help, then it would much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

0x80010117  means:

> RPC_E_CALL_COMPLETE Call context
>   cannot be accessed after call
>   completed.

Not that it helps!

Are you using WSRM?  It may not be properly configured.  If your not using it then remove the *Feature* from Server Manager.

Comment: Yep, take it out unless you need it.